# How to fix slider squished banner images in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm using a slider at my homepage created in Slider Revolution all images of the slider are squished horizontally how they wil be fixed? link of my homepage is motoringinvestments.com

I checked all settings in slider revolution there is no css applied but i don't knwo wher is the issue.

Comment: This site is for questions about programming

Answer (score -1):

Examining the CSS properties of the slider images in browser dev tools, I can see that the slide images have these styles set:
width: 100%
height: 100%

This is the problem as the slider has a certain width and height and the image is being forced to conform to it.   These styles are certainly coming from Slider Revolution unless you've added some custom javascript that adds them yourself.

Look here for the "Respect Aspect Ratio" setting, as turning this on may solve your problem:  https://themes.zone/docs/how-to-make-slider-revolution-responsive/